# Cannot enable Bluetooth on Tinkerboard (Armbian)

Tags: linux, bluetooth, armbian

I've got an ASUS Tinker Board device. It is running Armbian (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS / 5.10.60).

```
$ uname -a
Linux tinkerboard 5.10.60-rockchip #21.08.1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 25 19:43:43 UTC 2021 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The device is connected to Audio Receiver via HDMI cable.

In short, I'm trying to stream the audio from my phone to Audio Receiver via Tinker Board via Bluetooth and I cannot pair the phone with Tinkerboard.

I tried to open Bluetooth settings (Menu->Settings->Bluetooth Adapters). Nothing happens. Window appears and closes immediately.

```
# blueman-adapters
blueman-adapters 01.01.50 ERROR    Adapter:53 __init__  : No adapter(s) found
```

```
# bluetoothctl devices
No default controller available
```

```
# dmesg | grep -i blue
[    1.249497] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    1.249597] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    1.249618] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    1.249637] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    1.249675] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.461374] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    4.461391] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    4.461403] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    4.461456] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    4.477617] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    4.477661] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    4.477691] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[    4.477713] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
```

```
# service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-01-12 00:33:19 CET; 51min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 963 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4739)
     Memory: 1.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─963 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 12 00:33:19 tinkerboard systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan 12 00:33:19 tinkerboard bluetoothd[963]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Jan 12 00:33:19 tinkerboard systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 12 00:33:19 tinkerboard bluetoothd[963]: Starting SDP server
Jan 12 00:33:19 tinkerboard bluetoothd[963]: kernel lacks bnep-protocol support
Jan 12 00:33:19 tinkerboard bluetoothd[963]: System does not support network plugin
Jan 12 00:33:19 tinkerboard bluetoothd[963]: Bluetooth management interface 1.18 initialized
```

```
# hcitool dev
Devices:
```

```
# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

```
# lsmod | grep -i blue
```

As far as I understand, the bluetooth is implemented in the RTL8723 chip:

```
# lsmod | grep 87
r8723bs               499712  0
```

```
# dmesg | grep 8723
[   11.732800] r8723bs: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   11.737243] RTL8723BS: module init start
[   11.737260] RTL8723BS: rtl8723bs v4.3.5.5_12290.20140916_BTCOEX20140507-4E40
[   11.737264] RTL8723BS: rtl8723bs BT-Coex version = BTCOEX20140507-4E40
[   11.872845] RTL8723BS: rtw_ndev_init(wlan0)
[   11.873772] RTL8723BS: module init ret =0
[   13.734707] rtl8723bs: acquire FW from file:rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin
[   43.309445] RTL8723BS: rtw_set_802_11_connect(wlan0)  fw_state = 0x00000008
[   50.849151] RTL8723BS: rtw_set_802_11_connect(wlan0)  fw_state = 0x00000008
[   50.912171] RTL8723BS: start auth
[   50.914273] RTL8723BS: auth success, start assoc
[   50.925153] RTL8723BS: rtw_cfg80211_indicate_connect(wlan0) BSS not found !!
[   50.925175] RTL8723BS: assoc success
[   51.063472] RTL8723BS: send eapol packet
[   51.068690] RTL8723BS: send eapol packet
[   51.069246] RTL8723BS: set pairwise key camid:4, addr:68:02:b8:xx:xx:xx, kid:0, type:AES
[   51.073836] RTL8723BS: set group key camid:5, addr:68:02:b8:xx:xx:xx, kid:1, type:AES
```

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 1bcf:0007 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:481a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB Audio
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
# lspci
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.
```

```
# lshw

# lshw
tinkerboard
    description: ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
    product: Rockchip RK3288 Asus Tinker Board S
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smp
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 0
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 816MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-cpu:1
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@1
          size: 816MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-cpu:2
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 2
          bus info: cpu@2
          size: 816MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-cpu:3
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 3
          bus info: cpu@3
          size: 816MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 4
          size: 2000MiB
  *-usbhost:0
       product: DWC OTG Controller
       vendor: Linux 5.10.60-rockchip dwc2_hsotg
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1
       logical name: usb1
       version: 5.10
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
     *-usb
          description: USB hub
          product: USB2.0 Hub
          vendor: Genesys Logic, Inc.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@1:1
          version: 32.98
          capabilities: usb-2.00
          configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-usb:0
             description: Mouse
             product: USB Optical Mouse
             vendor: Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
             physical id: 3
             bus info: usb@1:1.3
             version: 0.14
             capabilities: usb-2.00
             configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=2Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: Keyboard
             product: Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
             vendor: Dell Computer Corp.
             physical id: 4
             bus info: usb@1:1.4
             version: 1.08
             capabilities: usb-1.10
             configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
  *-usbhost:1
       product: DWC OTG Controller
       vendor: Linux 5.10.60-rockchip dwc2_hsotg
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2
       logical name: usb2
       version: 5.10
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
  *-usbhost:2
       product: EHCI Host Controller
       vendor: Linux 5.10.60-rockchip ehci_hcd
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3
       logical name: usb3
       version: 5.10
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
     *-usb
          description: Audio device
          product: USB Audio
          vendor: Generic
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@3:1
          version: 0.00
          serial: 201405280001
          capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
          configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: dummy0
       serial: 02:9e:9c:16:01:c2
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=dummy driverversion=5.10.60-rockchip
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 2c:4d:54:xx:xx:xx
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=st_gmac driverversion=Jan_2016 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
  *-network:2
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 6
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: f0:03:8c:xx:xx:xx
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs driverversion=5.10.60-rockchip ip=192.168.0.6 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

```
# Extract from the /boot/config-5.10.60-rockchip

CONFIG_SERIAL_DEV_BUS=y
CONFIG_BT_HCIUART_3WIRE=y
CONFIG_BT_HCIUART_SERDEV=y
# CONFIG_BT_HCIUART_RTL - is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT - is not set
```

### TinkerOS

In case if I install TinkerOS (kernel v4.4), Bluetooth works as expected. I believe I can use it, but the fact that this distribution is 2 years old... I'd like to try configure Armbian first.

Following is the same output for TinkerOS

```
# uname -a
Linux tinkerboard 4.4.132+ #1 SMP Wed Aug 21 19:15:55 CST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

```
# bluetoothctl devices
[NEW] Controller F0:03:8C:xx:xx:xx R-Pi [default]
```

```
# dmesg | grep -i blue
[    2.005682] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    2.005754] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.005775] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.005792] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.005846] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.116728] Bluetooth: Virtual HCI driver ver 1.5
[    3.116976] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.116991] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.117002] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.117690] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth SDIO driver ver 0.1
[    6.272220] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.272237] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.272260] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    6.272282] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.272289] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.272301] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.272314] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[    6.272324] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[    6.273304] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'uart_rts_gpios' property of node '/wireless-bluetooth[0]' - status (0)
[    6.273313] [BT_RFKILL]: bluetooth_platdata_parse_dt: get property: uart_rts_gpios = 139.
[    6.273326] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: can't parse 'BT,power_gpio' property of node '/wireless-bluetooth[0]'
[    6.273350] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'BT,reset_gpio' property of node '/wireless-bluetooth[0]' - status (0)
[    6.273357] [BT_RFKILL]: bluetooth_platdata_parse_dt: get property: BT,reset_gpio = 149.
[    6.273379] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'BT,wake_gpio' property of node '/wireless-bluetooth[0]' - status (0)
[    6.273386] [BT_RFKILL]: bluetooth_platdata_parse_dt: get property: BT,wake_gpio = 146.
[    6.273407] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'BT,wake_host_irq' property of node '/wireless-bluetooth[0]' - status (0)
[    6.273415] [BT_RFKILL]: bluetooth_platdata_parse_dt: get property: BT,wake_host_irq = 151.
[    6.273426] [BT_RFKILL]: bluetooth_platdata_parse_dt: clk_get failed!!!.
[   12.763584] Bluetooth: Out-of-order packet arrived (7 != 0)
```

```
# service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-01-12 10:40:07 CET; 10min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 686 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─686 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 12 10:40:06 tinkerboard bluetoothd[686]: Bluetooth daemon 5.43
Jan 12 10:40:07 tinkerboard bluetoothd[686]: Starting SDP server
Jan 12 10:40:07 tinkerboard bluetoothd[686]: Bluetooth management interface 1.10 initialized
Jan 12 10:40:07 tinkerboard bluetoothd[686]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jan 12 10:40:07 tinkerboard bluetoothd[686]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jan 12 10:40:07 tinkerboard bluetoothd[686]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jan 12 10:40:19 tinkerboard bluetoothd[686]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jan 12 10:40:19 tinkerboard bluetoothd[686]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

```
# hcitool dev
Devices:
        hci0    F0:03:8C:xx:xx:xx
```

```
# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

```
# lsmod | grep -i blue
```

```
# lsmod | grep 87
8723bs               1757184  0
```

```
# dmesg | grep 8723
[   10.315776] RTW: rtl8723bs v5.1.7.4_24878.20171031_BTCOEX20170728-6b4e
[   10.315782] RTW: rtl8723bs BT-Coex version = BTCOEX20170728-6b4e
```

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0007 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:481a Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
# lshw
tinkerboard
    description: ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
    product: Tinker Board
    vendor: ASUS
    serial: 170604358400383
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smp
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 0
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1800MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-cpu:1
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@1
          size: 1800MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-cpu:2
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 2
          bus info: cpu@2
          size: 1800MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-cpu:3
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 3
          bus info: cpu@3
          size: 1800MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 4
          size: 2012MiB
  *-usbhost:0
       product: EHCI Host Controller
       vendor: Linux 4.4.132+ ehci_hcd
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3
       logical name: usb3
       version: 4.04
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
     *-usb
          description: Audio device
          product: USB Audio
          vendor: Generic
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@3:1
          version: 0.00
          serial: 201405280001
          capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
          configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-usbhost:1
       product: DWC OTG Controller
       vendor: Linux 4.4.132+ dwc2_hsotg
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2
       logical name: usb2
       version: 4.04
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
  *-usbhost:2
       product: DWC OTG Controller
       vendor: Linux 4.4.132+ dwc2_hsotg
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1
       logical name: usb1
       version: 4.04
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
     *-usb
          description: USB hub
          product: USB2.0 Hub
          vendor: Genesys Logic, Inc.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@1:1
          version: 32.98
          capabilities: usb-2.00
          configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-usb:0
             description: Mouse
             product: USB Optical Mouse
             vendor: Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
             physical id: 3
             bus info: usb@1:1.3
             version: 0.14
             capabilities: usb-2.00
             configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=2Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: Keyboard
             product: Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
             vendor: Dell Computer Corp.
             physical id: 4
             bus info: usb@1:1.4
             version: 1.08
             capabilities: usb-1.10
             configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
  *-network:0
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: f0:03:8c:xx:xx:xx
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 2c:4d:54:xx:xx:xx
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp aui bnc mii fibre 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=st_gmac driverversion=March_2013 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.136 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

Could be related to:

- [Bluetooth adapter not detected on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1310775/bluetooth-adapter-not-detected-on-linux)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674562/how-to-use-rtl8723bs-bluetooth-in-linux-5-10

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I switched to kernel v4.4 using the `armbian-config` tool.

The latest working Linux Kernel v5 version is v5.4, but it is not available in the APT repo.

```
$ uname -a
Linux tinkerboard 4.4.213-rockchip #2 SMP Wed Aug 25 20:21:35 UTC 2021 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

```
$ bluetoothctl list
Controller F0:03:8C:xx:xx:xx tinkerboard [default]
```

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    1.530654] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    1.530719] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    1.530738] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    1.530755] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    1.530819] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.591845] Bluetooth: Virtual HCI driver ver 1.5
[    2.592069] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    2.592083] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    2.592092] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    2.592102] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    2.592111] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    2.592283] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    2.592538] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth SDIO driver ver 0.1
[    3.769482] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    3.769493] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    3.769507] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    3.769520] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[    3.769526] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[199926.043310] Bluetooth: Unexpected start frame (len 612)
[199930.193181] Bluetooth: Unexpected start frame (len 612)
[199941.969641] Bluetooth: Unexpected start frame (len 612)
[199976.117041] Bluetooth: Unexpected start frame (len 612)
[200103.591928] Bluetooth: Unexpected start frame (len 612)
[200105.640193] Bluetooth: Unexpected start frame (len 612)
[200133.866821] Bluetooth: Unexpected start frame (len 612)
```

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5572 SanDisk Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:481a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB Audio
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
# lshw
tinkerboard
    description: ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
    product: ASUS Tinker Board
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smp
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 0
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1800MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-cpu:1
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@1
          size: 1800MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-cpu:2
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 2
          bus info: cpu@2
          size: 1800MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-cpu:3
          description: CPU
          product: cpu
          physical id: 3
          bus info: cpu@3
          size: 1800MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          capabilities: half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm cpufreq
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 4
          size: 2009MiB
  *-usbhost:0
       product: EHCI Host Controller
       vendor: Linux 4.4.213-rockchip ehci_hcd
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3
       logical name: usb3
       version: 4.04
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
     *-usb
          description: Audio device
          product: USB Audio
          vendor: Generic
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@3:1
          version: 0.00
          serial: 201405280001
          capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
          configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-usbhost:1
       product: DWC OTG Controller
       vendor: Linux 4.4.213-rockchip dwc2_hsotg
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2
       logical name: usb2
       version: 4.04
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
  *-usbhost:2
       product: DWC OTG Controller
       vendor: Linux 4.4.213-rockchip dwc2_hsotg
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1
       logical name: usb1
       version: 4.04
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
     *-usb
          description: USB hub
          product: USB2.0 Hub
          vendor: Genesys Logic, Inc.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@1:1
          version: 32.98
          capabilities: usb-2.00
          configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-usb
             description: Mass storage device
             product: Cruzer Switch
             vendor: SanDisk
             physical id: 3
             bus info: usb@1:1.3
             version: 1.27
             serial: 4C530303530629122440
             capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi
             configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-scsi
       physical id: 4
       bus info: scsi@0
       logical name: scsi0
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
  *-network:0
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: f0:03:8c:xx:xx:xx
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs ip=192.168.0.6 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 6
       logical name: p2p0
       serial: f2:03:8c:xx:xx:xx
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
  *-network:2 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       logical name: dummy0
       serial: 82:f7:3c:xx:xx:xx
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=dummy driverversion=1.0
  *-network:3
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 8
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 2c:4d:54:xx:xx:xx
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp aui bnc mii fibre 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=st_gmac driverversion=March_2013 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.4 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

```
# service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-02-03 09:48:51 CET; 4 days ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1671 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4495)
     Memory: 1.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1671 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 03 09:48:51 tinkerboard systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Feb 03 09:48:51 tinkerboard bluetoothd[1671]: Starting SDP server
Feb 03 09:48:51 tinkerboard bluetoothd[1671]: kernel lacks bnep-protocol support
Feb 03 09:48:51 tinkerboard bluetoothd[1671]: System does not support network plugin
Feb 03 09:48:51 tinkerboard bluetoothd[1671]: Bluetooth management interface 1.10 initialized
Feb 03 09:48:54 tinkerboard bluetoothd[1671]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.63 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 03 09:48:54 tinkerboard bluetoothd[1671]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.63 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 05 17:20:23 tinkerboard bluetoothd[1671]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_38_53_9C_xx_xx_xx/fd0: fd(44) ready
Feb 05 17:24:48 tinkerboard bluetoothd[1671]: SUSPEND request rejected: Bad State (49)
Feb 05 17:24:48 tinkerboard bluetoothd[1671]: SUSPEND request rejected: Bad State (49)
```

```
# hcitool devices
Devices:
        hci0    F0:03:8C:xx:xx:xx
```

```
# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```